# Automatic GeoZoomLevel

Tags: geographics

I was wondering what the automatic GeoZoomLevel for Mathematica was. For instance,

```
GeoGraphics[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]]
```

seems to display New York City at a GeoZoomLevel of 10, but

```
GeoGraphics[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]]
```

seems to display the US at a GeoZoomLevel of 4. How does Mathematica decide which GeoZoomLevel to use?

Answer (score 5):

The core of the problem seems to be that you need the two geo-positions that define the bounding box of the region you are looking at. Mathematica has two *similar* functions for that: `GeoBounds` and `GeoBoundingBox`

```
ny = Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}];
us = Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"];

GeoBounds[ny]
GeoBoundingBox[ny]
(* {{40.4774, 40.9175}, {-74.2591, -73.7003}} *)
(* {GeoPosition[{40.4774, -74.2591}], GeoPosition[{40.9175, -73.7003}]} *)
```

From the `GeoBounds` output, the zoom-level can directly be estimated

```
GIS`EstimateZoom[GeoBounds[#]] & /@ {ny, us}
(* {11, 4} *)
```

As you see, there is a discrepancy in the zoom-level of NY because

```
Options[GeoGraphics[
  Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]], 
  GeoZoomLevel]
(* {GeoZoomLevel -> 10} *)
```

However, there are some more arguments to `` GIS`EstimateZoom `` and the estimation depends on other factors like the geo-server. Nevertheless, the implementation of this function is not too long and it should be easy enough to understand it for your purpose.

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
GIS`EstimateZoom;
PrintDefinitions[GIS`EstimateZoom]
```